# compare 2 array and return the index of the same value

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a large array and a small array, for example

```
A = np.array([1,2,3])
B = np.array([3,4,5,6,7,8,2,1])
```

I can use `np.intersect1d` to get the same value,
but if I want to get the index (in large array B)of same value, for this example,it should be `[0,6,7]`,is there any command to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.in1d()` to get a Boolean array that represents the places where items of `A` appears in `B`, then using `np.where()` or `np.argwhere()` function you can get the indices of the True items:

```
In [8]: np.where(np.in1d(B, A))[0]
Out[8]: array([0, 6, 7])
```

Or as mentioned in comments `np.in1d(B, A).nonzero()[0]`. However the way you wanna choose here depends pretty much on the reset of your program and where/how you wanna use the results. In addition you can run benchmarks on all the methods in both short and large arrays to see which one is more appropriate in which situation.

Comment: Or maybe `np.in1d(B, A).nonzero()[0]`

Comment: @coldspeed Sure, added to the answer.